# Django Internationalization doesn't work (makemessages doesn't find .py file)

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I'm trying to internationalize my Django site with I18N. When I do the makemessages. Bit that did not get the text of the view.py. I have done the following things:

```
# my flow
PROJECT
- LOCALE
- MYSITE
  - urls.py
  - settings.py
- APP1
  - views.py
- APP2
- APP3      
manage.py

# settings.py
LANGUAGES = (
     ('it', 'Italiano'),
     ('en', 'English'),
            )
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'it'
USE_I18N = True
LOCALE_PATHS = ('home/project/locale/',)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( ...
                      'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
                     )   
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (...,
                      'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                     )

 # views.py

 from django.utils.translation import ugettext as tra
 text = tra("this is a text")
 ...

 # template.html
 ...
 {% trans 'Dashboard' %}
 ....
```

from the root (where is manage.py) when I do "python manage.py makemessages.py en-l" I get only a django.po with text from html file and not from views.py. I also tried with "python manage.py makemessages.py en-l-e html,py" but it doesn't work. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`makemessages` looks for very specific patterns in your code; `tra()` is *not* one of those patterns.

From the [`makemessages` command source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py#L74) you can see the `xgettext` command line tool is instead instructed to look for:
`gettext_noop`, `gettext_lazy`, `ngettext_lazy`, `ugettext_noop`, `ugettext_lazy`, `ungettext_lazy`, `pgettext`, `npgettext`, `pgettext_lazy` and `npgettext_lazy` (in addition to the `_()` callable).

Change your `views.py` code to:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
text = _("this is a text")
```

to follow the widespread `gettext` conventions, or use:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext
text = ugettext("this is a text")
```

Best to stick to the original `translation.*` methods or `_()`, here.